# Interacting with other Mage block classes from a template

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento, magento-1.7

I'm currently trying to modify the pagination template (`/app/design/frontend/default/mytheme/template/page/html/pager.phtml`) to only show the pagination links and a link that toggles between paginated and showing all items on a single page.

I've got the latter figured out:

```
<div class="show-all-toggle">
    <a class="show-all" href="<?php echo $this->getLimitUrl('all') ?>">Show All</a>
</div>
```

And I know how to get a list of all available pagination limits:

```
$this->getAvailableLimit();
```

However, I can't get the default limit that's been set in the admin backend.

I'm really not clear on the relationship between templates and block classes, but this template is associated with [Mage_Page_Block_Html_Pager](http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Page/Mage_Page_Block_Html_Pager.html), so I know that `$this` has all the member variables and functions of that class.

I also know that [Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid](http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Adminhtml/Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid.html) has a property called `$_defaultLimit`, which should be the default pagination limit set in the admin panel. But how do I access this class property from a different template? Or am I going about this completely the wrong way?

Comment: What about `$this->getLimit();`? Why you can't use it?

Comment: @Zyava: Unfortunately that only gets the current limit. So when the user first visits the store, then `$this->getLimit()` would indeed get the default limit. But once the user clicks on the "Show All" link, the current limit is set to `all`, and that's what `getLimit()` returns. So it wouldn't work for this use case.

Comment: If your pager block is inside `<block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" ...` - you can try `$this->getParentBlock()->getDefaultPerPageValue()`.

Comment: @Zyava: That's brilliant! Could you write that as an answer so I can mark it as correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your pager block is inside `<block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" ...` - you can try `$this->getParentBlock()->getDefaultPerPageValue()`.